# Where are stickies ( Sticky Notes) stored on mac 10.9.3?

Tags: macos, stickies

i deleted an important note on stickies. And i retrieved an old version of it in time machine under preferences / widgets. but the setup appears to have changed in my upgrade to mavericks and I can't open the note. I'm trying to open a "post-mavericks" version in my time machine and I can't find where it is.

i saw a post that said look under Library/Preferences/Container, i have no such folder or binary document. Please help.

Comment: There's `~/Library/Containers` – maybe you want that?

Answer (score 2):

Stickies are typically stored in a DB under `~/Library/StickiesDatabase`. You can try to copy this file to your current running user from your Time Machine backup and open the Stickies application to see if that works. Make sure you don't overwrite the existing file, or make a copy of it before moving the one from your backup to your working user.